# Upload files in drupal to be indexed in solr

Tags: drupal, solr

Are there any modules that let you upload files which will then get indexed by Apache solr. I have used the attachment module that sits on top of the solr integration module. But this involves the creation of basic pages and/ articles then having a file upload widget to upload files to them which then gets indexed and is searchable.

But i do not want to create pages to upload my files.This is the requirement.

my stack is apache solr 3.2 , drupal 7 solr integration module and solr attachment module(which i am not happy with for the above reason !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unavailable so far. There are modules in drupal like file-entity which le t you upload files so do the core drupal module but they never get indexed by the apache solr attachments module.

I would like to be stand corrected.